# String.Format - query metadata from the format string

Tags: c#

Is there any function to query the expected inputs and formats from a format string - i.e. one intended as the first argument to the `String.Format` function?

e.g. given:

```
"On {0:yyyyy-MM-dd} do {1} and earn {2:C2}"
```

I'd like to get back something like:

```
{"yyyyy-MM-dd", null, "C2"}
```

I guess a regex is one possibility but is there anything precanned that hooks into the same logic as `String.Format`?

Comment: Have you reviewed [FormattableString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring(v=vs.110).aspx), in particular it's [GetArguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring.getarguments(v=vs.110).aspx) method. I don't know if this will do what you need, but it might be a start...?

Comment: @RB. that's only for interpolated strings, which *can't* appear without their arguments. There is no need to retrieve the *placeholders* in this case

Comment: @Geoff_h what are you trying to do? String.Format itself doesn't *parse* the format string. It ends up calling the internal [StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,2c3b4c2e7c43f5a4) method which treats the format strings only as delimited strings. It doesn't try to parse them. The format is passed directly to each argument type's `ToString()` method

Comment: What I really need to do in practice is find out how many arguments a given format string requires. But this led me to the more general question of whether it was possible to extract the other data - format string and I guess alignment as well. But looking at the implementation this seems unlikely.

Comment: @geoff_h you can use a regex. The implementation is written that way because formatting is *critical* to performance. Returning the fully formatted result takes almost the same time as only parsing the format string. You should take care to account for escaped braces though ({{, {})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.Format itself doesn't parse the format string. It ends up calling the internal [StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,2c3b4c2e7c43f5a4) method which treats the format strings only as delimited strings. It doesn't try to parse them. The format is passed directly to each argument type's formatter method. String formatting performance is critical, both for the runtime and applications.

You can use a regular expression to parse the format string. You'd need to take care of escaped braces ({{, {}) and alignment strings.

The regex `{(?<index>\d+)(,(?<algn>-?\d+?))?(:(?<fmt>.*?))?}` takes extracts the index, alignment and format segments as named groups. It doesn't take care of escaped braces *explicitly. It will avoid `{{ {}` but not `{{2,20:N{}`:

```
var regex=new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"{(?<index>\d+)(,(?<algn>-?\d+?))?(:(?<fmt>.*?))?}");
var matches=regex.Matches("asdf{0:d2} {1:yyyy-MM-dd} {2,-20:N2}");
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-15} {2,-15}",
                       match.Groups["index"].Value, 
                       match.Groups["algn"].Value,
                       match.Groups["fmt"].Value);
}
```

This will return :

```
0                d2             
1                yyyy-MM-dd     
2     -20        N2
```

The `(?<name>...)` syntax captures a pattern and exposes it as a named group. `(?<index>\d+)` captures a sequence of digits and exposes it as the group `index`.

The `?` in `.*?` specifies a non-greedy match. Typically a regex is greedy - it will capture as many characters match a pattern as possible. By using `.*?` the regex will capture as few characters as possible before the next pattern starts. That's why the optional `algn` group stops at `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are no standard means for that. Use Regex, it's easy:

```
var args = new List<string>();
var str = "On {0:yyyyy-MM-dd} do {1} and earn {2:C2}";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"\{\d+[^\{\}]*\}");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
  string obj = null;
  var split = match.ToString().Split(':');
  if (split.Length == 2) obj = split.Last().Trim(' ', '}', '{');
  args.Add(obj);
}

// Result: args = {"yyyyy-MM-dd", null, "C2"}
```

Comment: That regex though won't work. A good regex doesn't require additional splitting. This regex doesn't take care of the full format string specification either, with alignment and length specifications.

Comment: You had to *split and trim* afterwards. It won't handle alignment either